# TensorFlow/Keras - expected global_average_pooling2d_1_input to have shape (1, 1, 2048) but got array with shape (7, 7, 2048)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, resnet, imagenet

I'm fairly new to TensorFlow and Image Classification, so I may be missing key knowledge and is probably why I'm facing this issue.

I've built a `ResNet50` model in TensorFlow for the purpose of image classification of Dog Breeds using the `ImageNet` library and I have successfully trained a neural network which can detect various Dog Breeds.

I'm now at the point in which I would like to pass a random image of a dog to my model for it to spit out an output on what it thinks the dog breed is. However, when I run this function, `dog_breed_predictor("<file path to image>")`, I get the error `expected global_average_pooling2d_1_input to have shape (1, 1, 2048) but got array with shape (7, 7, 2048)` when it tries to execute the line `Resnet50_model.predict(bottleneck_feature)` and I don't know how to get around this.

Here's the code. I've provided all that I feel is relevant to the problem.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from keras.preprocessing import image
from tqdm import tqdm

from sklearn.datasets import load_files
np_utils = tf.keras.utils

# define function to load train, test, and validation datasets
def load_dataset(path):
    data = load_files(path)
    dog_files = np.array(data['filenames'])
    dog_targets = np_utils.to_categorical(np.array(data['target']), 133)
    return dog_files, dog_targets

# load train, test, and validation datasets
train_files, train_targets = load_dataset('dogImages/dogImages/train')
valid_files, valid_targets = load_dataset('dogImages/dogImages/valid')
test_files, test_targets = load_dataset('dogImages/dogImages/test')

#define Resnet50 model
Resnet50_model = ResNet50(weights="imagenet")

def path_to_tensor(img_path):
    #loads RGB image as PIL.Image.Image type
    img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
    #convert PIL.Image.Image type to 3D tensor with shape (224, 224, 3)
    x = image.img_to_array(img)
    #convert 3D tensor into 4D tensor with shape (1, 224, 224, 3)
    return np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)

from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions

def ResNet50_predict_labels(img_path):
    #returns prediction vector for image located at img_path
    img = preprocess_input(path_to_tensor(img_path))
    return np.argmax(Resnet50_model.predict(img))

###returns True if a dog is detected in the image stored at img_path
def dog_detector(img_path):
    prediction = ResNet50_predict_labels(img_path)
    return ((prediction <= 268) & (prediction >= 151))

###Obtain bottleneck features from another pre-trained CNN
bottleneck_features = np.load("bottleneck_features/DogResnet50Data.npz")
train_DogResnet50 = bottleneck_features["train"]
valid_DogResnet50 = bottleneck_features["valid"]
test_DogResnet50 = bottleneck_features["test"]

###Define your architecture
Resnet50_model = tf.keras.Sequential()
Resnet50_model.add(tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(input_shape=train_DogResnet50.shape[1:]))
Resnet50_model.add(tf.contrib.keras.layers.Dense(133, activation="softmax"))

Resnet50_model.summary()

###Compile the model
Resnet50_model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="rmsprop", metrics=["accuracy"])
###Train the model
checkpointer = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath="saved_models/weights.best.ResNet50.hdf5",
                                                 verbose=1, save_best_only=True)

Resnet50_model.fit(train_DogResnet50, train_targets,
                  validation_data=(valid_DogResnet50, valid_targets),
                  epochs=20, batch_size=20, callbacks=[checkpointer])

###Load the model weights with the best validation loss.
Resnet50_model.load_weights("saved_models/weights.best.ResNet50.hdf5")

###Calculate classification accuracy on the test dataset
Resnet50_predictions = [np.argmax(Resnet50_model.predict(np.expand_dims(feature, axis=0))) for feature in test_DogResnet50]

#Report test accuracy
test_accuracy = 100*np.sum(np.array(Resnet50_predictions)==np.argmax(test_targets, axis=1))/len(Resnet50_predictions)
print("Test accuracy: %.4f%%" % test_accuracy)

def extract_Resnet50(tensor):
    from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50, preprocess_input
    return ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False).predict(preprocess_input(tensor))

def dog_breed(img_path):
    #extract bottleneck features
    bottleneck_feature = extract_Resnet50(path_to_tensor(img_path))
    #obtain predicted vector
    predicted_vector = Resnet50_model.predict(bottleneck_feature) #shape error occurs here
    #return dog breed that is predicted by the model
    return dog_names[np.argmax(predicted_vector)]

def dog_breed_predictor(img_path):
    #determine the predicted dog breed
    breed = dog_breed(img_path)
    #display the image
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)
    cv_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    plt.imshow(cv_rgb)
    plt.show()
    #display relevant predictor result
    if dog_detector(img_path):
        print("This is a dog and its breed is: " + str(breed))
    elif face_detector(img_path):
        print("This is a human but it looks like a: " + str(breed))
    else:
        print("I don't know what this is.")

dog_breed_predictor("dogImages/dogImages/train/016.Beagle/Beagle_01126.jpg")
```

The image I'm feeding into my function is from the same dataset that was used to train the model - I wanted to see myself if the model is working as intended - so this error makes it extra confusing. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [nessuno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2891324/nessuno)'s assistance, I figured out the issue. The problem was indeed with the `pooling` layer of `ResNet50`.

The following code in my script above:

```
return ResNet50(weights='imagenet',
                include_top=False).predict(preprocess_input(tensor))
```

returns a shape of `(1, 7, 7, 2048)` (admittedly though, I do not fully understand ***why***). To get around this, I added in the parameter `pooling="avg"` as so:

```
return ResNet50(weights='imagenet',
                include_top=False,
                pooling="avg").predict(preprocess_input(tensor))
```

This instead returns a shape of `(1, 2048)` (again, admittedly, I do not know ***why***.)

However, the model still expects a 4-D shape. To get around this I added in the following code in my `dog_breed()` function:

```
print(bottleneck_feature.shape) #returns (1, 2048)
bottleneck_feature = np.expand_dims(bottleneck_feature, axis=0)
bottleneck_feature = np.expand_dims(bottleneck_feature, axis=0)
bottleneck_feature = np.expand_dims(bottleneck_feature, axis=0)
print(bottleneck_feature.shape) #returns (1, 1, 1, 1, 2048) - yes a 5D shape, not 4.
```

and this returns a shape of `(1, 1, 1, 1, 2048)`. For some reason, the model still complained it was a 3D shape when I only added 2 more dimensions, but stopped when I added a 3rd (this is peculiar, and I would like to find out more about why this is.).

So overall, my `dog_breed()` function went from:

```
def dog_breed(img_path):
    #extract bottleneck features
    bottleneck_feature = extract_Resnet50(path_to_tensor(img_path))
    #obtain predicted vector
    predicted_vector = Resnet50_model.predict(bottleneck_feature) #shape error occurs here
    #return dog breed that is predicted by the model
    return dog_names[np.argmax(predicted_vector)]
```

to this:

```
def dog_breed(img_path):
    #extract bottleneck features
    bottleneck_feature = extract_Resnet50(path_to_tensor(img_path))
    print(bottleneck_feature.shape) #returns (1, 2048)
    bottleneck_feature = np.expand_dims(bottleneck_feature, axis=0)
    bottleneck_feature = np.expand_dims(bottleneck_feature, axis=0)
    bottleneck_feature = np.expand_dims(bottleneck_feature, axis=0)
    print(bottleneck_feature.shape) #returns (1, 1, 1, 1, 2048) - yes a 5D shape, not 4.
    #obtain predicted vector
    predicted_vector = Resnet50_model.predict(bottleneck_feature) #shape error occurs here
    #return dog breed that is predicted by the model
    return dog_names[np.argmax(predicted_vector)]
```

whilst ensuring the parameter `pooling="avg"` is added to my call to `ResNet50`.

Comment: I liked the solution but anyone can put more information on the reasons for the change and the reasons for the dimensions?

Comment: I had the same problem but since mine had 4 dimensions, I deleted one `bottleneck_feature = np.expand_dims(bottleneck_feature, axis=0)` line from the final code and it worked like a charm!

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful! In order to cleanup the method a bit, I ended up rewriting mine like this:
`predicted_vector = Resnet50_model.predict(np.expand_dims(np.expand_dims(bottleneck_feature,
                                                              axis=0), axis=0))`

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of [ResNet50](https://keras.io/applications/#resnet50) says something about the constructor parameter `input_shape` (emphasis is mine):

> input_shape: optional shape tuple, **only to be specified if include_top is False** (otherwise the input shape has to be  (224, 224, 3) (with 'channels_last' data format) or (3, 224, 224) (with 'channels_first' data format). It should have exactly 3 inputs channels, and width and height should be no smaller than 197. E.g. (200, 200, 3) would be one valid value.

My guess is that since you specified `include_top` to `False` the network definition pads the input to a bigger shape than 224x224, so when you extract the features you end up with a feature map and not with a feature vector (and that's the cause of your error).

Just try to specify and input_shape in this way:

```
return ResNet50(weights='imagenet',
                include_top=False,
                input_shape=(224, 224, 3)).predict(preprocess_input(tensor))
```

Comment: It made no difference unfortunately, still the same error!

Comment: That's unfortunate. However, the problem should be in the input + feature extraction part, because clearly, the expected input to the average pooling layer is bigger than the expected by the pooling layer. Of maybe is the pooling layer itself that's not required. In the documentation, check the other optional parameter `pooling` and try with pooling=None, check whick is the output shape of the extacted features in that case

Comment: Actually, the error has seemed to change when including `input_shape`. The error is now `Error when checking input: expected input_3 to have shape (244, 244, 3) but got array with shape (224, 224, 3)`. Any ideas?

Comment: I've figured it out! I'll create an answer.